# What version of Minecraft: Java Edition has the best performance?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, performance

So, I am going to start a private Minecraft server. But I get poor performance in 1.18. I am considering 1.8.9, but I don't know if this is the best option. I am using a Rasberry Pi 4 B.

Comment: I don’t know if this is something that is very easy to measure. Performance can depend on many factors besides just what version you use, and it also depends on how many features you are willing to sacrifice.

Comment: I am going to use a Rasberry  Pi, And it is gonna be an Open PVP world. If that helps.

Comment: I don’t know if any version will have good performance on a raspberry pi, it’s not made for that kind of stuff

Comment: As early a version as possible. SMP came out somewhere around alpha 1.0 but you might not be able to find the server software that old, and it was full of bugs. Minecraft has been getting slower and slower in every single version. Back then, it was designed to run in 256MB RAM

Comment: I saw a video where a Rasberry Pi 4 B ran a 1.17.1 server with 8 people easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, there are five main versions of Minecraft used in servers:

- Latest version - servers that need the latest features.
- Previous version - servers that are waiting for the latest version to be well-supported by plugins and mods.
- 1.12 - servers that need the good performance, and don't have a reason to use old combat.
- 1.8 - servers that prefer the old-style combat.
- 1.7 - servers that do not need (or like all of) 1.8's features. Typically PvP practice servers.

Using optimisation mods can help performance. The most popular are [PaperMC](https://papermc.io/) and [Spigot](https://www.spigotmc.org/) which are both a drop-in replacement for the vanilla server JAR, Paper being easier to set up. However, they both change vanilla mechanics.

If you want something a little more vanilla-friendly, a combination of [Phosphor](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/phosphor) and [Lithium](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/lithium) is a bit better.

If you are just running an small SMP, the latest version should be fine. If you encounter performance issues, I'd recommend first installing Phosphor and Lithium, and then trying PaperMC if you don't see any difference.

Comment: I tried 1.12.2, And the client has really good performance, i think i will use 1.12.2 and PaperMC for my server. Do you have any recommendations to how i can ask more questions without annoying people?

Comment: hey, @UltraGato , just make your questions as clear as possible and give the details needed and u should be fine.  Some people will be annoyed no matter what you do, and it doesnt help how many rules are on this site  =).  Good luck, and have fun on your server!